# Как обратиться к массиву в массиве?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel4

Я получаю картинку из инпута, вот dd переменной которая получает весь гет и пост:
[image]

```
$input['name'] - выведет имя
```

а вот при таком же обращении к аватару выдает ошибку.
У меня еще установлен Intervention image, может как-то с помощью него можно сразу сохранять картинку из инпута и как мне обратиться к массиву avatar?

Comment: `$input['avatar']->basename` так пробовали?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/XTIdWm0.png

Comment: В `dd()` у вас же $request->all() , `$request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();`

Comment: $input['avatar']['path']

Comment: Попробуйте так `$input['avatar']->getClientOriginalName();`  я привел все действия в своём ответе который помогут вам это реализовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так `echo $input['avatar']->getClientOriginalName();`

**[Laravel 5 and Laravel 4 Cheat Sheet](http://www.phplab.info/categories/cheet-sheets/laravel-5-and-Laravel-4-cheat-sheet)**

Если у вас в `dd()` $request->all(),или $request->only(...) что то в этом духе,То получать инфо загружаемого файла можно следующим образом:

> Имейте в виду что `Input::file('avatar')` и `$request->file('avatar')` они идентичны.

```
// Использовать файл, который был загружен
Input::file('avatar');
// Определите, был ли загружен файл
Input::hasFile('avatar');
// Свойства файла доступа
Input::file('name')->getRealPath();
Input::file('name')->getClientOriginalName();
Input::file('name')->getClientOriginalExtension();
Input::file('name')->getSize();
Input::file('name')->getMimeType();
```